# I cant find a way to get the Maximum number in the array (Ar.getMax()). My output is constantly 0

Tags: java, arrays, oop

Im trying to get the maximum number in the array, using the function getMax(), but the output is always 0.

When input is: 12 87 3 10 55 69 40
Result should be: 69
Instead result is: 0

```
  public int getMax()
      {
          int x=1;
          int y=0;   

          for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
              {
                  if(i!=size-1)
                  {
                      if(arr[i]>arr[x])
                      {
                          y=arr[i];
                          x++;
                      }
                  }
              }
          return y;
      }
```

Comment: If you actually want `x` for some reason, then `x++;` should be `x = i;`, your `if(i!=size-1)` seems odd, why are you looping to two before `size`? Where is `arr` defined and initialized? What is `size`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the default maximum value to the first value in the array.  Then, iterate thru the array comparing that value to the next one in the array.  If is is larger then assign it to max.  Continue to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

As 89 is larger, I think you want the local maximum of the longest non-decreasing subsequence in the array. The problem is not well formulated, so probably no homework.

```
array: 12 87 3 10 55 69 40
sequences: 12 87
           3 10 55 *69* answer
           40

int maxOfLongestSubsequence(int[] a) {
   int maxSeqLength = 0;
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   int seqStart = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; ++i) {
       if (i == 0 || i == a.length - 1 || a[i] < a[i - 1]) { // New subsequence
           int seqLength = i - seqStart;
           if (i - seqLength > maxSeqLength) {
               maxSeqLength = seqLength;
               max = a[i - 1];
           }
           seqStart = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Formulate the problem. Depict the data as I did. And program it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the max of an int array like this:

```java
int [] numbers = new int[]{12,87,3,10,55,69,40};

        int max = numbers[0];
        for(int current : numbers) {
            max = current >= max ? current : max;
        }
        System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: What if I pass `int[] numbers = {-1,-2,-3};`? Shouldn't I get `-1` instead of `0`?

Comment: @dguy, assign `int max= numbers[0];`

Comment: Thanks, man. Edited my answer. I thought his numbers are always positive. :)